# Create cross html table from Php Array

Tags: php, html

```
Array
(
[Group1] => Array
    (
        [someDay1] => Array
            (
                [empty] => 5
                [full] => 8
            )

        [someDay2] => Array
            (
                [empty] => 2
                [full] => 6
            )

    )

[Group2] => Array
    (
        [someDay1] => Array
            (
                [empty] => 2
                [full] => 6
            )

        [someDay2] => Array
            (
                [empty] => 2
                [full] => 4
            )

    )
```

)

I would like to create cross table according to Groups and Dates, this is the output that i want:

[image: Table]

Is it possible to create cross table like this with this kind array? I am confused.

Comment: You want to create it in HTML ?

Comment: yes, i want to create this cross table in html

Comment: So here you can find the solution : http://html.com/tables/rowspan-colspan/

Comment: You can use Jquery Datatables for this perhaps, or even plain html, pass your array to your view or html file and structure your HTML accordingly. Lots of examples are available online on how to structure your html to make a pivot/cross table

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do :

```css
table, tr, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2"></th>
    <th>Someday1</th>
    <th>Someday2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Group1</td>
    <td>Empty</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Full</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Group2</td>
    <td>Empty</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Full</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Here is a tutorial to help you](http://html.com/tables/rowspan-colspan/)

Comment: actually i mean create this with php loops.